# Create Running Sum in SQL

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to calculate a running sum of one column partitioning with respect to another column, using SnowFlake SQL. Here is an example input table:

```
ID_1    DATE_1      FLAG
A      10/12/2016   1
A      10/31/2016   1
A      11/8/2016    1
B      2/1/2017     1
B      3/27/2017    1
```

I want to compute a running sum between FLAG and DATE_1 (in ascending order), partitioning over ID_1. Thus, the result in this example should be:

```
ID_1    DATE_1      FLAG_RUNNING_SUM
A      10/12/2016   1
A      10/31/2016   2
A      11/8/2016    3
B      2/1/2017     1
B      3/27/2017    2
```

I tried to do recursive Common Table Expressions (CTEs) for this (see here: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/with.html) but Snowflake does not support window functions in recursive CTEs, as per that document.

Does anyone know how I can do this, ideally cleanly?

I suspect that recursive joins/CTEs are somehow the answer, but I am open to non-recursive solutions as well. Whatever works.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a window fucntion:

```
select t.*,
       sum(flag) over (partition by id_1 order by date_1) as FLAG_RUNNING_SUM
from t;
```

Comment: This was absolutely correct. Just to unpack this query, what the second part of the select statement means (I think) is: sum(flag) where we partition over id_1, and order by  ascending date_1. This effectively creates a running sum of flag (i.e. FLAG_RUNNING_SUM). Correct?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/sum.html show how this works quite nicely

Comment: @Josh, also note that the SUM window function has an implicit "window frame" (between unbounded preceding and current row). That is crucial to understanding how this becomes a running sum, rather than say an aggregate sum of the partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query in snowflake as well:

```
select t.*,
        rank()  over (partition by id_1 order by date_1) as FLAG_RUNNING_SUM
from t
```